# Bar chart in ggplot not grouping by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a bar chart in `ggplot2` where each factor gets the mean of the observations.  However, the plot is the mean of the entire population, and is not breaking out/grouping by the factor, which is what I want

Here is the chart:
[image]

When I calculate the mean for the groups, there is a difference, which is what I want to plot.

```
  US      Foreign
1 89.76   124.02
```

Here is the mean of the entire column in the dataframe

```
mean(clients$OrderSize)
[1] 96.71
```

Here is the structure of the dataframe.  I have CountryType as a factor, as this is what I want to group by:

```
str(clients)
'data.frame':   252774 obs. of  4 variables:
$ ClientID     : Factor w/ 252774 levels "58187855","59210128",..: 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 ...
$ Country      : Factor w/ 207 levels "Afghanistan",..: 196 60 139 196 196 40 40 196 196 196 ...
$ CountryType  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Foreign","US": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
$ OrderSize    : num  12.95 21.99 5.00 7.50 44.5 ...
```

This is the call I am making:

```
ggplot(data = clients, aes(x=CountryType, y=mean(OrderSize))) + geom_bar() + ylab("")
```

And I tried explictely setting CountryType as a factor with no luck:

```
ggplot(data = clients, aes(x=factor(CountryType), y=mean(OrderSize))) + geom_bar() + ylab("")
```

Do I need to pre-calculate the means for the two groups before I call `ggplot` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something more like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(letters[1:2],each = 25),y = 1:50)
ggplot(dat,aes(x = x,y = y)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "bar")
```

[image]

As a general note, avoid idioms like `aes(y = value)` where `value` is a single value, rather than the name of a column in your data frame. That's just not how **ggplot2** is intended to be used. (Although all rules can be broken in certain circumstances...)

Comment: Thanks.  I got this to work correctly.  One question re: `stat_summary` - why use `geom = "bar"` there and not explicitly call `geom_bar`?  I'm not confused by `ggplot` using `qplot` versus `geom_bar` or `geom = bar`, just wondering why there are different implementations of the same thing.

Comment: @mikebmassey `stat_summary` is a different beasts. The idea is that it rolls the computation of summary statistics **and** the specification of a geom into a single call. Doing something like `ggplot(...) + stat_summary(...) + geom_bar()` with no geom specification in the stat will generate an error, I believe.

Comment: @mikebmassey I should add that all the `stat_`'s behave this way, not just `stat_summary`. You should be specifying the geom in the stat call.

Comment: @Joran I never really understood the `stat_`s until your simple explanation here.  Thank you +1